# How to set the expiry time for a cookie in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

Suppose i have a stored a value in cookiestore. 
I want to set  the expiry time also. The below is the snippet which i had written. 
Could any one give working code of placing a value in cookie, expiry time setting and after that checking the cookie.

I had referenced the js file for cookie is in index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
$cookieStore.put("Name", 'cookievalue', { 'expires': now });
```

Though i have set the expiry time, still its getting the cookie value.
Reading the cookie:

```
$window.alert($cookieStore.get('Name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var expireDate= new Date();
expireDate.setHours(17,45,0,0);
$cookies.put("Name", "cookievalue", {
        expires: expireDate
        });
```

Comment: For me expiry at that instance its working. The problem when i try to give some time e.g: 5.35 PM, like its not working.

Comment: @ins do you want the cookie to expire at 5.45 pm on the day its created?